# When creating notebook, got 'Service role does not have permission to access the LocationUri {}' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

When I create an AWS EMR Notebook, got the below error. The service role is EMR_Notebook_DefaultRole.

```
Service role does not have permission to access the LocationUri {}
```

What would be the root cause? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your role for jupyter doesnt have acces to s3 location where notebooks are planned to be stored.

You can modify the policy of the s3 bucket that this notebook shows at the time of creation.

Try changing it to sometthing like

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::632293491421:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-emr-resources-632293491421-eu-west-1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::632293491421:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-emr-resources-632293491421-eu-west-1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure you use correct number inplace of `632293491421`, which will be showing at your bucket

Comment: Where do I get the number 632293491421?

Answer (score 0):

While creating your notebook chose "EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole" role

This image might help you:

[image: EMR Notebbook]